# 'Access to path denied' when trying to use Nsight with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, access-denied, nsight

My program builds and compiles fine. However when I try to run a performance analysis using Nsight, I get the following error:

[image]

This is what I do from VS2015:
Nsight -> Start Performance Analysis -> Select CUDA trace settings -> Launch

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I tried to remove the Read-Only attribute of the c:\temp folder, but it didn't work. Now it says Read-Only (only applies to files in folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it by setting a different folder for the output under Nsight -> Options -> Analysis -> Report Directory